# Texture Mapping a 3D object with a 2D texture in openGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, texture-mapping

I have a cube that is made of triangles, so 8 vertices and corresponding incides to create the triangle. Im having trouble creating the texture coordinates for this cube. I tried using values like:

```
    float amt = 1.0f;
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(0.0f, 0.0f));
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(amt, 0.0f));
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(amt, amt));
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(0.0f, amt));

m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(0.0f, 0.0f));
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(amt, 0.0f));
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(amt, amt));
m_texBuffer.push_back(Texel(0.0f, amt));
```

I get wierd visual results with varing values of amt. I understand that since an image can be smaller than the actual object that there is not nessaseraly a one to one correspondance so I tried to make amt a small value but still no go.

Comment: where? i dont see a check box nor do i see an answer

Comment: I meant on your other questions. I was just noting that you hadn't (at the time I posted that) accepted any of the answers, and was letting you know about the feature.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I think he needs 15 reputations for that. So until he gets that, he can't accept answers

Comment: @NicolBolas, Ah! I remember one guy saying I want to accept but I can't because it needs 15. Maybe he mis-clicked the up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regular textures that sampling range in each coordinate is 0 to 1, independent of the sampling resolution.

Unfortunately your code is absolutely non-telling, it could be anything. We really need to see more of it, especially the actual OpenGL calls.

**EDIT due to comment**

Loading image data one must tell OpenGL the layout of the data in the buffer. The essential information are

(parameters to glTexImage)

- numer of components
- arrangement of components
- size of each component

(parameters to glPixelStore)

- alignment (0 for tight packing, otherwise alignment to 1, 2 or 4 bytes)
- pixel and row run lenghts (usually those are 0)

Please see the documentation of [glTexImage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) and [glPixelStore](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml) and set them apropriately for your image data.

Comment: I'm actually getting a rainbow psychedelic effect on the objects. Its almost like colored snow on a TV screen. I have no idea why thats happening.

Comment: @Katianie: Then you didn't load your texture correctly. Completely different problem. Please add a screenshot to yor questions in the future. See my answer's edit.